# Display HTML in Android browser with element sizes specified in CSS

Tags: android, html, css

How do I display an element with a size of 1.5 x 2.5 inch in the Android browser? Let's consider the html bellow.

On my desktop computer, browser in a "normally" sized window, it displays the content in 2 rows, each block with size 1.5 x 2.5 inch so as specified in the html.
When I make the browser's window smaller, to correspond to a size of a smartphone, so there is one or two blocks per row, all the time each block with the size 1.5 x 2.5 inch.
That's exactly how I would like to see it also on my smartphone.

Unfortunately on the smartphone (default browser with default settings in Android 4.0) I see the content in 2 rows, each block having a size around 0.5 x 0.8 inch. I.e. it is like normally sized desktop scaled down to a tiny smartphone screen - that's not what I want. I want to see blocks with the size 1.5 x 2.5 inch as specified in CSS.

Is there maybe some meta tag that says to android that the page was designed with mobile devices in mind so that Android will not try to do some "desktop sites" optimizations on it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style>
    div {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 1.5in;
        height: 2.5in;
        background: #AAAAAA;
        margin: 1em 1em;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
    <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is resolved by adding this directive to the head section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"></meta>
```

Eventually I found the answers hidden here:
[Media Query and Android Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16054603/media-query-and-android-device)
and [Media queries not behaving as expected on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6047884/media-queries-not-behaving-as-expected-on-android)